# Pandas - Remove leading Zeros from String but not from Integers

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a column in my dataset that looks like the following:

| Identifier |
| --- |
| 09325445 |
| 02242456 |
| 00MatBrown |
| 0AntonioK |
| 065824245 |

The column data type is object.
What I'd like to do is remove the leading zeros **only from column rows where there is a string**. I want to keep the leading zeros where the column rows are integers.

Result I'm looking to achieve:

| Identifier |
| --- |
| 09325445 |
| 02242456 |
| MatBrown |
| AntonioK |
| 065824245 |

Code I am currently using (that isn't working)

```
def removeLeadingZeroFromString(row):
    if df['Identifier'] == str:
        return df['Identifier'].str.strip('0')
    else:
        return df['Identifier']
        
df['Identifier' ] = df.apply(lambda row: removeLeadingZeroFromString(row), axis=1)
```

Comment: You'll want to use ```lstrip``` not ```strip``` as the latter would remove trailing zeros as well.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to try to convert `Identifier` [`to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html). Test where the converted values [`isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html), using this mask to only [`str.lstrip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lstrip.html) (strip leading zeros only) where the values could not be converted:

```
m = pd.to_numeric(df['Identifier'], errors='coerce').isna()
df.loc[m, 'Identifier'] = df.loc[m, 'Identifier'].str.lstrip('0')
```

`df`:

```
  Identifier
0   09325445
1   02242456
2   MatBrown
3   AntonioK
4  065824245
```

---

Alternatively, a less robust approach, but one that will work with number only strings, would be to test where not [`str.isnumeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html):

```
m = ~df['Identifier'].str.isnumeric()
df.loc[m, 'Identifier'] = df.loc[m, 'Identifier'].str.lstrip('0')
```

*NOTE This fails easily `to_numeric` is the much better approach if looking for all number types.

Sample Frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Identifier': ['0932544.5', '02242456']
})
```

Sample Results with `isnumeric`:

```
  Identifier
0   932544.5  # 0 Stripped
1   02242456
```

---

DataFrame and imports:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Identifier': ['09325445', '02242456', '00MatBrown', '0AntonioK',
                   '065824245']
})
```

Comment: Thank you @henryecker your alternative worked, I got an error with your first piece of code **"AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'isna'"**.

Comment: Some  how you've passed an array to to_numeric instead of a Series. You can use `np.isnan` instead of course, `import numpy as np` then `m = np.isnan(pd.to_numeric(df['Identifier'], errors='coerce'))`

Answer (score 0):

Use `replace` with regex and a [positive lookahead](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-20):

```
>>> df['Identifier'].str.replace(r'^0+(?=[a-zA-Z])', '', regex=True)
0     09325445
1     02242456
2     MatBrown
3     AntonioK
4    065824245
Name: Identifier, dtype: object
```

Regex: replace one or more 0 (`0+`) at the start of the string (`^`) if there is a character (`[a-zA-Z]`) after 0s (`(?=...)`).

Comment: thank you for your answer but this strips the zeros from the numbers too. I only want the leading zeros to be striped where there are strings

Comment: I updated my answer. Does it work better?

Comment: yes this is perfect thanks. Can you explain what is happening please?

Comment: I add `^` to indicate to match the start of the string,

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I'm not very familiar with regex so I really appreciate the explanation

Comment: @PythonBeginner. Don't forget to accept an answer if this fits your need.